# Difference between two ways of reading a web page (html) using Java

Tags: java, html, internet-explorer, http, httpurlconnection

**First way** is just to url.openStream, then InputStreamReader,

```
    StringBuffer temp = new StringBuffer();
    URL url = new URL(addr);
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(),"ISO-8859-1"), BUFFER_SIZE );
    int charsRead;   
    char[] copyBuffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];   
    while ((charsRead = bf.read(copyBuffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1)  { 
        temp.append(copyBuffer, 0, charsRead);
    }
    bf.close();
```

I found that the result differ from that from IE/Chrome.

**Second way** is to use HttpURLConnection first, then getInputStream, then InputStreamReader

```
    URL url = new URL(addr);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer temp = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        temp.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
```

This returns exactly what's in the IE if I view source.

**So my questions are**:

1. Why sometimes the first method using url.openStream returns a different html than the one I read from IE?  There are tags missing, number of carriages returns are different (which is questions 2)
2. I noticed that the html from first method have reasonable carriage returns.  The one from second method had no carriage return.  IE view source shows even more carriage returns than the first method.  Why is this?

Thanks!

Comment: What site did you visit to test your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sites give different outputs based on different things like, the User-Agent, the Accept headers sent, cookies/sessions available, accepted language header etc

These things will change the html that is served as it adapts to the client's needs.

So in your case, you have a different User-Agent, and other headers too, so the response is probably different because of that.